# How to write a pipeline for a pull request for lint and run tests

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, pull-request, npm-run

I never wrote pipelines in github actions, I was asked to create a pipeline for a pull request for repositories in github using the commands:

```
npm run lint;
npm run test;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub's own [`setup-node`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-node-js-environment) Action has examples of how to do this. Based on the docs there, something like this placed in a YAML file in the `.github/workflows` directory should work:

```yaml
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: '16'
- run: npm install
- run: npm lint
- run: npm test
```